# EditText setError not positioning at the right position

Tags: android, android-layout

A validation check is performed on a edit text on button click event. When validation fails, Error Code icon shows at right position in Edit text box but its arrow enclosing the string always show up at one position about its desired position. Following is the snapshot for better understanding :

[image]

Following is the code :

```
else {
  ET_UNAME.setError("Please Enter User Name");
  ET_UNAME.requestFocus();
}
```

Layout is Relative Layout. Is it that I am missing something or it is a known bug. Please give suggestion so that I release the app soon with the Error code. Any turnaround?

Comment: @Amit Vaghela: I am looking for a solution to this problem also.  I don't see the link you mentioned above.  Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your layout's root element, find the following line and remove it.

`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It worked. But there is one minor issue. When I drop down and bring up android keyboard for last edit text field which gets covered when I bring up keyboard since this Edit text field is at the bottom of layout, Error code sign shows up at little upper incorrect position. Also, if possible can you explain the logic behind the removing of app layout behaviour code.

Comment: Wrap your layout in a `ScrollView`. This will fix it.